# Get list from pandas DataFrame column headers by more than 1000 columns

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe with more than 1000 columns. I would like to get a list of all column headers, but everything i tried so far works up to 1000 column names.

```
list(df.columns.values)
list(df)
```

This is the output what i got:

[image]

Is there any possibility to get a list of ALL column headers?

Answer (score 1):

All of the columns are there, they are just not being printed.

Try this!

```
for col in df.columns: 
    print(col)
```

Or, to make it a list...

```
mylist = []
for col in df.columns:
    mylist.append(col)
```

Comment: the first solution works - the print cols. But the second shows the only 1000 column headers. I suppose that the LIST in python is so limited.

Comment: I think the interpreter you're using only prints 1000, but they are there (in the ...), if the answer worked plz accept it!